# loading images few images from a bigger image file JavaScript

Tags: javascript

QUESTION: How can I load in 1 to 9 random images from a file containing hundreds of other images with JavaScript?

Just wanted to know if anyone here has any ideas for me. Because in the example below I am having trouble finding out how this website does it.

Thanks for the help.

[example here](https://pyrotoz.com/)

Comment: I think you're looking for CSS spritesheets.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a better response from the community.

Comment: @stuartd I could make some random number picker thing that would pick out what images to load. My question is how can i load in those images without loading in the rest of the images from the file

Answer (score 2):

If each pokemon is an object with multiple properties (type, stats, etc), one of those properties were "imageid", you could use Math.random or a similar method to generate a random number between 1 and x, where x is your total number of images. Then a for...in loop to find the pokemon with the corresponding imageid, and display the appropriate image.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking this too. Im just having a problem of how I could load in those images 1 to 9 at a time randomly without loading all the other images in the background.